# Failed without error message: wkhtmltopdf

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

PDF not save my folder in localhost.
I'm getting an error : Failed without error message: wkhtmltopdf "C:\Users\Fujitsu\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1470.tmp.html" "C:\Users\Fujitsu\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1480.tmp.pdf"

```
$pdf_html = view('frontend.pdf.pdf_template', $data)->render();
    $pdf = new Pdf;
    $pdf->addPage($pdf_html);


    if (!$pdf->saveAs(public_path() . '/assets/invoices_pdf/invoice_' . $tran_id . '.pdf')) {
        $error = $pdf->getError();
        print '<pre>'; print_r($error); print('</pre>'); die();
    }
```

I'm using Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

have you checked that you can read write to that paths? I had that kind of errors several times in the past and 80% of the time was problems with the path (insufficient permisiones, malformed paths, paths that doesn't exist...)

Also could be that the path to the wkhtmltopdf binary is not correct, or that there is a missing dependency. For instance in Linux you need to have xvfb installed.